# Auto round value by decimal datatype in C# programming

Tags: c#, .net

I have problem with one variable that I have declared with decimal datatype and it need to be with decimal datatype I don't wanna change that datatype because I need it on another part as well.

> What exactly I need

I am getting **2.12** as discount value. that i have assign to one variable dynamically.

```
//I am getting 2.12 here
 decimal discount = Convert.ToDecimal(label.text); //it convert to 3 (round figure)
```

Comment: What's the value of `label.text`? Is that the 2.12 or is it 3?

Comment: Your code works fine and as expected.

Comment: @DanielEdwards it's 2.12 but it's converts in to 3

Comment: Try specifying your locale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying a culture.

```
decimal discount = Convert.ToDecimal(label.text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: How can i assign direct value like `decimal discount = 2.12`

Comment: You can do the following - `decimal discount = 2.12m`. More info here about how decimals work: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx